# AWSでS3のs3fsの証明バージョン2から4にバージョンアップ手順について

Tags: aws, amazon-s3

AWSでS3のs3fsの証明バージョン2から4にバージョンアップする手順について、
教えていただけますでしょうか。
署名バージョン2のままですと、6月24日に廃止のためです。
S3バケット・オブジェクトにアクセスできなくなるためです。

#### 追記

インストールは別の方が何年も前に対応しました。そのため、前任者の対応が不明の状態です。
その方に確認してみます。
以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

Release verson 1.79 にアップデートすればいいみたいです。

https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse/releases/tag/v1.79
https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse/pull/116

Comment: ありがとうございます。
アップデートの手順などご存知でしたら、手順方法を共有して頂ければ幸いです。
以上、よろしくおねがいします。

Comment: @pass_f_0201 追加の情報を求める場合などは、返信したい投稿の下にある「コメント追加」からコメントを行うようにしてください。